# Is it possible to highlight areas of a background image using multiple DIVs and CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have two DIVs over the top of a single background image. I want to darken all areas around the two DIVs and keep the image unaffected within the two DIVS, creating a kind of spotlight effect.

I tried using shadows around the DIVs but both cast a shadow over each other.

Is there any way to darken all areas outside of the 2 DIVS?

E.g.

```
<div class="background-image">
    <div class="light-area-1"></div>
    <div class="light-area-2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share an image of desired output?

Comment: Can probably be done using `mix-blend-mode`.

Comment: You mean something like a binocular view?

Comment: Are the light-area divs needing to be actual elements or are you just wanting the visual effect?

Comment: Here's what I have so far: https://refuelled.org/ I've added the same background image to both DIVs but position is not precise so it doesn't align with the background image.

Answer (score 0):

If there are just two 'spotlights' and the effect is to be purely visual you could use pseudo elements and clip-paths to overlay the spotlights:

```css
.spotlit {
  --bg: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/200/300);
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), var(--bg);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 80vmin;
  height: 70vmin;
  position: relative;
}

.spotlit::before,
.spotlit::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: var(--bg);
  background-size: cover;
}

.spotlit::before {
  clip-path: polygon(20% 20%, 50% 20%, 50% 40%, 20% 40%);
}

.spotlit::after {
  clip-path: polygon(70% 60%, 90% 60%, 90% 95%, 70% 95%);
}
```

```html
<div class="spotlit">
</div>
```

However, if the spotlights are needed as actual elements a similar approach lays them above the main, shadowed element using clip-path as above. This way you can have as many  spotlights as required.

```css
.background-image {
  --bg: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/200/300);
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), var(--bg);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 80vmin;
  height: 70vmin;
  position: relative;
}

.light-area-1,
.light-area-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: var(--bg);
  background-size: cover;
}

.light-area-1 {
  clip-path: polygon(20% 20%, 50% 20%, 50% 40%, 20% 40%);
}

.light-area-2 {
  clip-path: polygon(70% 60%, 90% 60%, 90% 95%, 70% 95%);
}
```

```html
<div class="background-image">
  <div class="light-area-1"></div>
  <div class="light-area-2"></div>
</div>
```

The shapes can be changed given clip-path's various options such as circle which may be useful to make them look more like an actual spotlight.

Comment: Thanks for this. Food for thought. I didn't know about clip-path. Here's what I have so far just using background images on DIVs positioned relatively. https://refuelled.org